# ADA Object-Orientation Compile Error -- I don't understand the error

Tags: oop, inheritance, ada95

I hope that you can advise me.   I'm trying to use ADA 95's  Object Oriented Features for the first time, and I want  two derived classes,  cyclicgroup and polyggroup, to call the put() method belonging to their base class,
abstractGroup.  But instead of tracing up the class hierarchy as I expected, the compiler just tells me that I have a type mismatch in the call to put().  How do I tell the compiler to recognize the connection between the objects?

Here are the 5 files, with all the extraneous stuff removed,  and the attempted compile:

grpdriver2.adb:

with Ada.Text_IO; use Ada.Text_IO;
with Ada.Command_Line; use Ada.Command_Line;

with groupstuff2;
with subgrphandler2;

```
procedure grpdriver2 is
    cycg:  groupStuff2.cyclicgroup;
    polyg: groupStuff2.polygonGroup;
begin

    cycg := groupstuff2.createCyclicGroup( 10);
    subgrphandler2.put(cycg);   -- line 13

    ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    polyg := groupstuff2.createPolygonGroup( 10);
    subgrphandler2.put(polyg);     -- line 18

end grpdriver2;
```

.................................................................................................................

groupstuff2.ads:

with Ada.Text_IO; use Ada.Text_IO;
with Ada.Command_Line; use Ada.Command_Line;

package groupstuff2 is

```
type abstractGroup is tagged record
    x: integer;
end record;


type cyclicGroup is new abstractGroup with record
    y: integer;
end record;


function createCyclicGroup( size: in integer)  return cyclicGroup ;

----------------------------------------

type polygonGroup is new abstractGroup with record
    null;
end record;

function createPolygonGroup( size: in integer) return polygonGroup ;
```

end groupstuff2;

.......................................................................................

groupstuff2.adb:

package body groupstuff2 is

```
procedure put( g: in abstractGroup) is
    x: integer;
begin
    x := 1;
end put;


function createCyclicGroup( size: in integer)  return cyclicGroup is
    cycg: cyclicGroup;
begin
    cycg.x := size;

    return cycg;

end createCyclicGroup;

function createPolygonGroup( size: in integer) return polygonGroup is
    polyg: polygonGroup;
begin
    polyg.x := size;


    return polyg;

end createPolygonGroup;
```

end groupstuff2;

..............................................................................

subgrphandler2.ads:

with Ada.Text_IO; use Ada.Text_IO;
with Ada.Command_Line; use Ada.Command_Line;

with groupstuff2;

package subgrphandler2 is

```
procedure  put( g: in groupStuff2.abstractGroup);
```

end subgrphandler2;

...........................................................................................

subgrphandler2.adb:

package body subgrphandler2 is

```
procedure  put( g: in groupStuff2.AbstractGroup) is

begin
        put("THIS IS A PUT STATMENT");      
end put;
```

end subgrphandler2;

COMPILE ATTEMPT:

C:\GNAT\2018\bin\ceblang>gnatmake  grpdriver2
gcc -c grpdriver2.adb
grpdriver2.adb:13:36: expected type "abstractGroup" defined at groupstuff2.ads:7
grpdriver2.adb:13:36: found type "cyclicGroup" defined at groupstuff2.ads:16
grpdriver2.adb:18:36: expected type "abstractGroup" defined at groupstuff2.ads:7
grpdriver2.adb:18:36: found type "polygonGroup" defined at groupstuff2.ads:25
gnatmake: "grpdriver2.adb" compilation error

Answer (score 0):

I cannot compile Ada95 code as I'm using GNAT CE 2018 (which only supports Ada 2012), but it seems that you need to add the `Class` attribute to the type of the argument of `put` in `subgrphandler2` to make it accept a class wide type (i.e. `groupStuff2.AbstractGroup`, and all of its extensions (inherited types)).

You also might want to make `groupStuff2.AbstractGroup` actually abstract by adding the `abstract` keyword to its definition (see below).

This (reformatted code) compiles on GNAT CE 2018 in Ada 2012 mode:

**group_driver_2.adb**

```
with Group_Stuff_2; 
with Sub_Group_Handler_2;

procedure Group_Driver_2 is

   Cycg  : Group_Stuff_2.Cyclic_Group;
   Polyg : Group_Stuff_2.Polygon_Group;

begin

   Cycg := Group_Stuff_2.Create_Cyclic_Group (10);
   Sub_Group_Handler_2.Put (Cycg);

   Polyg := Group_Stuff_2.Create_Polygon_Group (10);
   Sub_Group_Handler_2.Put (Polyg);

end Group_Driver_2;
```

**group_stuff_2.ads**

```
package Group_Stuff_2 is

   type Abstract_Group is abstract tagged 
      record
         X: Integer;
      end record;

   --  Cyclic_Group 

   type Cyclic_Group is new Abstract_Group with 
      record
         Y: Integer;
      end record;

   function Create_Cyclic_Group
     (Size: in Integer)  return Cyclic_Group;

   --  Polygon_Group 

   type Polygon_Group is new Abstract_Group with null record;

   function Create_Polygon_Group
     (Size: in Integer) return Polygon_Group ;

end Group_Stuff_2;
```

**group_stuff_2.adb**

```
package body Group_Stuff_2 is

   -------------------------
   -- Create_Cyclic_Group --
   -------------------------

   function Create_Cyclic_Group
     (Size : in Integer) return Cyclic_Group
   is
      Cycg : Cyclic_Group;
   begin
      Cycg.X := Size;
      return Cycg;
   end Create_Cyclic_Group;

   --------------------------
   -- Create_Polygon_Group --
   --------------------------

   function Create_Polygon_Group
     (Size : in Integer) return Polygon_Group 
   is
      Polyg: Polygon_Group;
   begin
      Polyg.X := Size;
      return Polyg;
   end Create_Polygon_Group;

end Group_Stuff_2;
```

**sub_group_handler_2.ads**

```
with Group_Stuff_2;

package Sub_Group_Handler_2 is

   procedure Put (G : in Group_Stuff_2.Abstract_Group'Class);

end Sub_Group_Handler_2;
```

**sub_group_handler_2.adb**

```
with Ada.Text_IO; use Ada.Text_IO;

package body Sub_Group_Handler_2 is

   procedure Put (G: in Group_Stuff_2.Abstract_Group'Class) is
   begin
      Put_Line ("Value of X is" & Integer'Image (G.X));      
   end Put;

end Sub_Group_Handler_2;
```

Comment: Thank you very much; I will try the change..  The ADA book that I was following was not clear on this point.   I was translating a Java program where the class infrastructure was much more straightforward.

Comment: If you happen to have a Java background, then this article, [Ada for the C++ or Java Developer](https://www.adacore.com/uploads_gems/Ada_for_the_C++_or_Java_Developer-cc.pdf), might also be of interest. The particular problem in this question, the use of the ```Class``` attribute, is discussed in section 8.2: Derivation and Dynamic Dispatch.